# Why does range iterating with _ blank identifier produce different values

Tags: go

I'm learning [Go](https://golang.org/) and having a great time so far.

The following code outputs the sum as `45`

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
   //declare a slice
   numSlice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
   var sum int = 0

   for num := range numSlice {                                                                                           
      sum += num
      fmt.Println("num =", num)
   }
   fmt.Println("sum =", sum)   
}
```

The following  code, where I use `_` the blank identifier to ignore the index in the for declaration outputs the sum as `55`

```
//declare a slice
numSlice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
var sum int = 0

for _,num := range numSlice {                                                                                           
   sum += num
   fmt.Println("num =", num)
}
fmt.Println("sum =", sum)
```

This has got me slightly stumped.  From my understanding the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank) is used to ignore the slice index .  But it also seems to be shifting the index and thereby ignoring the last element in the slice.

Can you please explain what's happening here and possibly why.  I'm assuming this is not a bug and is by design.  Go is so well designed so what would the possible use cases be for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: They don't like cross-posting. In the future, when your question is on the wrong site you should wait for a mod to move it instead of taking the initiative yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear that in mind in future.

Comment: But... sum of 1..10 **is** 55, not 45.

Comment: I would recommend you going through this section: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for. That should help you to understand `for` and `range` in Go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Single parameter range uses indexes, not values.  Because your indexes are also going up from 0 to 9 using range with a single param will add the indexes up from 0 to 9 and give you `45`

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
   //declare a slice
   numSlice := []int{0, 0, 0, 0}
   var sum int = 0

   for num := range numSlice {                                                                                           
      sum += num
      fmt.Println("num =", num)
   }
   fmt.Println("sum =", sum)   
}
```

### Output

```
num = 0
num = 1
num = 2
num = 3
sum = 6
```